# How to show/hide login block on main page based on button in header?

Tags: blocks, theming, users

I would like to ask the following:

My sections are lets say header, main page and footer.

I want to have a button in the header, and when it is pressed, another section comes up between header and main page showing the login form. (username and password fields must be displayed in parallel). In this section also I would like to have another button and when it is pressed, the section becomes bigger, showing the signup form.

For the show/hide functionality I will do it with HTML5, so no worries on this one.

But my question is a basic drupal architecture question that I do not know and I would need your help :)

What is the best approach to build the above? The steps below are correct?

1. Create a custom module to alter the standard login block it display it horizontally? Or this can be done with theming?
2. Create another block which will contain the 2 buttons and the login / sign up elements? If yes, in which section do I put this block? If I put it on header how then can I display the inbetween section?

Is there a drupal module that may help with the above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach you can consider as best as we won't be actually touching the core Drupal functionality and creating our custom module to tweak the core. You can also have a look at [logintoboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module it may help you to get the drop down effect for login form and login block on click of link once you do the configurations for the loggintoboggan. you may need to additional theming and some jquery code to tweak it more for signup.

Hope it helps.